# i am getting error like TypeError: Joi.strict is not a function

Tags: node.js, hapi

```
TypeError: Joi.strict is not a function
at Object.register (C:\Users\prakashkumar.m\cs test\if-contact-services\src\api\contact-create-validation\create-validation.js:233:26)
at internals.Server.register (C:\Users\prakashkumar.m\cs test\if-contact-services\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\server.js:495:35
)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node: internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async exports.compose (C:\Users\prakashkumar.m\cs test\if-contact-services\node_modules\@hapi\glue\lib\index.js:46:9)
at async exports.startServer (C:\Users\prakashkumar.m\cs test\if-contact-services\node_modules\@hpe\addison-engine\lib\index.js:23:3)
```

Node.js v18.17.1

i am getting this error when i try to upgrade my application (node and hapi)

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.